# PHP memcache confusion on install

Tags: php, memcached

So looking into using memcache in my web application I am reading up about `memcache` and `memcached`. Just looking to clarify some things. First when they say install memcached that means install memcache right? Just the d is for the daemon correct? There isnt something different to install for memcached vs memcache correct?

Then the second is the php library, memcache vs memcached. Which I understand Im just a bit confused with the installation part when someone says install memcache then I read other posts that says install memcached. This is the url I was planning to use to install memcache, of course with the latest versions:

http://mrphp.com.au/code/install-memcache-cpanel-running-centos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. install memcached library into your OS
2. install the php-client to work with memcache. It could be Memcache or Memcached.
3. if you'll choose Memcached, you will need to install necessary libevent version

[Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) client is more stable, but [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) has some interesting features.
Look at differences in functionality (just few functions) and if you really need these new features - take Memcached, otherwise - Memcache.

Comment: That is what Im confused about. Take the link above in my original post. It says to install memcache yet it points to the memcached installation. So is memcache a different library than memcached? Or is memcached just the daemon for memcache?

Comment: @John again: you need to install 2 things: library and client. library called memcached - there is nothing to choose :) But you have to choose client. You have 2 clients (Memcache and Memcached) - I gave you 2 links, where you can read differences. If you new in it, I recommend you to use Memcache client.